# Make kubernetes mount point only to azure files

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a kubernetes volume mount pointing to azure files. How do I restrict files present in azure files to my container?

My requirement is to push the files only to azure files but I shouldn't load the files back to the container.

```
      volumeMounts:
        - name: testlog
          mountPath: /app/testlog/
  volumes:
    - name: testlog
      azureFile:
        secretName: testlog-secret
        shareName: testlog
        readOnly: false
```

Comment: This is not suitable for your use case then. From the container's point of view this directory is just a regular file system directory; read/write operations are provided by Azure files driver. Container will see files which it's written before.

Comment: Egor is correct.  You will need to create an write only API key and have your container / process Issue an http POST to the storage account.  Depending on the language there are available SDK

Answer (score 1):

To manage the content within an Azure File PVC, you should

1) create the Storage Account before hand
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-sample-create-account

2) manage its content using the API directly within your container/application code
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api

for example to create a directly
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-directory
and files within that directory
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file

If you have a specific language and you do not want to use the http API directly, MSFT have created a few SKDs to manage Storage accounts

Here's an example in GO

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-file-go